# Trouble building a simple SparkSQL application

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

This is a pretty noob question.

I'm trying to learn about SparkSQL.  I've been following the example described here:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Everything works fine in the Spark-shell, but when I try to use sbt to build a batch version, I get the following error message:
`object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark`

Unfortunately, I'm rather new to sbt, so I don't know how to correct this problem.  I suspect that I need to include additional dependencies, but I can't figure out how.

Here is the code I'm trying to compile:

```scala
/* TestApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

case class Record(k: Int, v: String)

object TestApp {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
   import sqlContext._
   val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000)
   val records = data.map(i => new Record(i, "value = "+i))
   val table = createSchemaRDD(records, Record)
   println(">>> " + table.count)
 }
}
```

The error is flagged on the line where I try to create a SQLContext.

Here is the content of the sbt file:

```scala
name := "Test Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0"

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please answer your question using Your Answer section? The sbt community on StackOverflow would appreciate so much.

Answer (score 32):

As is often the case, the act of asking the question helped me figure out the answer. The answer is to add the following line in the sbt file.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.0.0"
```

I also realized there is an additional problem in the little program above.  There are too many arguments in the call to createSchemaRDD.  That line should read as follows:

```
val table = createSchemaRDD(records)
```

Comment: and to add Hive - libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.1.0"   - thanks mvnrepository.com !

Comment: nothing like searching for a problem and discovering that you solved the problem the previous year but you can't repeat the steps again ... what I had to do this time was close and reopen Intellij before it would consistently pick up the new libraryDependencies declaration. That might save someone else a few *hours* ...

Comment: Nice. As of Dec. 16'th 2019 it is libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4"

Answer (score 9):

Thanks! I ran into a similar problem while building a Scala app in Maven. Based on what you did with SBT, I added the corresponding Maven dependencies as follows and now I am able to compile and generate the jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue, in my case, i just copy pasted the below sbt setup from online with scalaVersion := "2.10.4" but in my environment, i actually have the scala version 2.11.8

so updated & executed sbt package again, issue fixed

```
name := "Test Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0"

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```